# Call a function in parent component's sibling in React

Tags: reactjs, components, state, react-props

I have a component structure like this:

**A** is the parent component. **B** and **C** are the child components of **A**; so, **B** and C are siblings. **D** is a child component of **C**.

Here is the structure:

```
A
  B - function 2
  C
    D - function 1
```

I need to call **function 1** in D to trigger/call **function 2** in B.

Here's what I have so far (easier to starting reading the following from bottom to top, meaning D -> C -> B -> A):

```
<A>
  <B triggerFunction2={}/> // not sure what to send to B to trigger function2  
  <C function1inA={}/>    // not sure how to get function1inA to trigger function2 in B
</A>

<B> 
   function2 = () => {
      console.log("function2 successfully triggered");
   }
</B>

<C>
  function1inC = () => {
    props.function1inA();
  }

  <D function1={function1inC}/> 
</C>

<D>
  // when doSomething is called, trigger function 1 
  doSomething = () => {
    props.function1();
  }  
</D>
```

Comment: You should read about [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

You can use refs to make this happen. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

You can reference component B in component A and pass that down to component C and then component D.

This worked for me in https://codesandbox.io/

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <A />
    </div>
  );
}

class B extends React.Component  {
  componentDidMount() {
  const { childRef } = this.props;
  childRef(this);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
  const { childRef } = this.props;
    childRef(undefined);
  }
  function2 = () => {
    console.log("function2 successfully triggered");
  };
  render() {
    return <span></span>
  }
}

class D extends React.Component  {
  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.props.callFunction2}></button>);
  }
}

class C extends React.Component  {
  render() {
    return (
  <D callFunction2={this.props.callFunction2} />
  )};
}

class A extends React.Component {
  callFunction2FromComponentA = () => {
    this.child.function2();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <B childRef={ref => (this.child = ref)} />
        <C callFunction2={this.callFunction2FromComponentA} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```